# Consulta SQL com ID a partir de uma combobox - C#

Tags: c#, sql

Estou montando um pequeno sistema onde eu criei um `Formulario` em que há um `Combobox` que lista o nome dos funcionários armazenados no banco e um `DataGrid` que mostra os serviços feito por eles *(valor, descrição e cliente)*.

[image: Imagem do Sistema]

Ao selecionar o funcionario no Combobox,eu queria que mostrasse os servicos feito por ele,entao eu criei

```
SELECT func_nome, serv_desc, serv_cliente, serv_valor FROM func_serv
INNER JOIN func_dados ON func_serv.func_id = func_dados.func_id
WHERE func_serv.func_id = //codigo da funcionaria;
```

[image: SQL]

Minha duvida é, ao pegar o índice do combobox selecionado, como posso usa-lo como parâmetro para minha consulta sql, substituindo aquela parte comentada do código.

Eu pensei em criar vários ifs, mas se for criado um novo funcionário, irei ter de por mais um if.

Me ajudem, por favor

Comment: como você preenche o Combobox? Se você pegar os dados diretamente do banco de dados, pode usar as propriedades DisplayMember e ValueMember do ComboBox e pegar o SelectedValue do combo com o ID selecionado.

Comment: conexao = new SqlConnection(conexao_sqlserver);
            SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("select func_nome from func_dados", conexao);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);

            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    cb_func_caderneta.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["func_nome"]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception erro)
            {
                throw erro;
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você concatenar o valor do comboxBox, usei o `@` para escapar a string para melhor visualização.

```
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT func_nome, serv_desc, serv_cliente, serv_valor FROM func_serv
                                INNER JOIN func_dados ON func_serv.func_id = func_dados.func_id
                                WHERE func_serv.func_id = " + comboBox1.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: Obrigado,acho que isso irá resolver meu problema, testei de uma maneira mais generica e vi que vai da certo.
agora so to procurando um jeito pegar o valor do combobox e passar pro DAL ,que é outra classe

Comment: Você pode passar o valor pro DAL por parâmetro, não? Se a resposta solucionou seu problema, peço que marque como resposta.

Comment: Eu teria que criar um metodo getCombo pra pegar o valor do combobox?

Comment: Algo assim: http://pastebin.com/8isc9B1B

Answer (score 0):

@Vinicius Caminha,
você pode usar o

> SelectedValue

. `Where meucampo = combobox.SelectedValue;`

Comment: Eu posso chamar a funçao SelectedValue dentro da pesquisa sql ?

Answer (score 0):

E se você fizesse algo assim:

```
public SqlDataReader lista_dados_servico(object idFuncionario)
{
    conexao = new SqlConnection(conexao_sqlserver);
    var query = @"SELECT func_nome, serv_desc, serv_cliente, serv_valor FROM func_serv
        INNER JOIN func_dados ON func_serv.func_id = func_dados.func_id
        WHERE func_serv.func_id = @idFuncionario";

    using (var comando = new SqlCommand(query, conexao))
    {
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idFuncionario", idFuncionario);

        return comando.ExecuteReader();
    }
}
```

e usasse assim:

```
var idFuncionario = comboBox1.SelectedValue;

var reader = lista_dados_servico(idFuncionario);

while (reader.Read())
{
    var index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

    int indexColunaNome    = 0,
        indexColunaServico = 1,
        indexColunaCliente = 2,
        indexColunaValor   = 3;

    dataGridView1[index, indexColunaNome].Value    = reader["func_nome"];
    dataGridView1[index, indexColunaServico].Value = reader["serv_desc"];
    dataGridView1[index, indexColunaCliente].Value = reader["serv_cliente"];
    dataGridView1[index, indexColunaValor].Value   = reader["serv_valor"];
}
```

isto não resolveria seu problema?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente alteraria a forma como você preenche o comboBox para:

```
conexao = new SqlConnection(conexao_sqlserver); 
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("select func_nome,func_id from func_serv", conexao); 
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
da.Fill(dt);

comboBox1.DataSource = (dt.Tables[0]);
comboBox1.DisplayMember = ("func_nome");
comboBox1.ValueMember = ("func_id");
```

Depois no IndexChanged do Combobox ou em um botão de pesquisa colocaria o código do @Laerte

```
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT func_nome, serv_desc, serv_cliente,serv_valor FROM func_serv
                            INNER JOIN func_dados ON func_serv.func_id = func_dados.func_id
                            WHERE func_serv.func_id = " + comboBox1.SelectedValue);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
da.Fill(dt);

Datagrid1.DataSource=dt.Tables[0];
```

Obs.: Caso o sistema não esteja organizado em camadas para uma melhor organização e Prática de Desenvolvimento de Sistema segue alguns links para possível estudo.

http://www.devmedia.com.br/desenvolvimento-em-3-camadas-conceitos/22277
https://rafaelnicolettdeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/07/04/projeto-em-camadas-c-crud/